# How to update static data in Parse?

Tags: ios, rest, parse-platform

I'm just starting out to use the Parse API and I am going to, among other things, use it to store some static data that my iOS apps will occasionally download.  I do, however, have a need to occasionally update this static data, but Parse isn't very clear on how to update that data once it is initially uploaded.

Parse's API docs show you how to upload files of the same name without overwriting existing data, but in this case that's exactly what I want to do.  **How do I upload updates to the same file?**

In this case I am using the REST API to upload the content.  I get the URL back to reach the content, but I am not able to update it by simply POSTing to the URL that it returns.  I get a 405 denied.  I try changing the HTTP method to PUT, but that results in a 403 Unauthorized.

Answer (score 0):

You can upload a new file, then update the Parse object with a reference to the new file. Each file gets its own unique permalink, so they cannot be "updated" with new content.

However you can update any object to point to the new file.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that you cannot update a static resource, but upload a new one.  This turns out to be four API calls:

1. Upload resource
2. Get File object
3. Update pointer
4. Delete old resource

Then for a client:

1. Get File object
2. Download static resource

Comment: This should be two API calls; uploading the resource gives you the file object and you don't typically delete the file as part of the process (others might have stale pointers to the file).

Comment: @ThomasBouldin This assumes that you had the file object to begin with.  If you're doing a true update to a static resource, there's no reason to have additional pointers to the file itself, but pointers to the API object.

Comment: Ah, so you mean that your steps would be 1. Fetch the containing PFObject so you know where the resource is, 2. Download the resource, 3. Upload a modified resource, 4. Update the object from (1)?